# Fetching Form-data in spring controller

Tags: spring-boot

Hi It might look like duplicate but its not.

I am building a rest api using spring boot and need to fetch form-data sent by client app in POST request.
for testing purpose I am using postman. So far i have tried below

```
@PostMapping("/feed/comment/add/{feedId}")
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> addComment(@RequestHeader(name = Constants.USER_ID_HEADER) int userId, 
            @PathVariable("feedId") int feedId,
            @RequestParam("comment") String comment
            ) {
        LOGGER.info("Received add comment request with comment:"+comment);

        return new ResponseEntity<BaseResponse>(new BaseResponse("You are not feed owner", RESPONSETYPE.ERROR), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```

this gives error "Required String parameter 'comment' is not present"

Second way tried:

```
@PostMapping("/feed/comment/add/{feedId}")
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> addComment(@RequestHeader(name = Constants.USER_ID_HEADER) int userId, 
        @PathVariable("feedId") int feedId,
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> values
        ) {
    for(String key: values.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key+":"+values.get(key));            
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<BaseResponse>(new BaseResponse("You are not feed owner", RESPONSETYPE.ERROR), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

this gives wired output:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymk97RU1BbJyR0m3F
Content-Disposition: form-data; name:"comment"

test comment
------WebKitFormBoundarymk97RU1BbJyR0m3F--
```

I'm pretty sure that with plane servlet i can access this using request.getParameter("comment")
not sure how i can fetch it in case of spring rest controller.

Answer (score 0):

"Required String parameter 'comment' is not present" this error happens when this paremeter is required but you didn't send it.

@RequestParam(value="comment", required=false) 
this will make the comment parameter optional. So if you missed sending the comment parameter its ok.